# Where content of StatefulWidget should be stored?

Tags: flutter, dart

I switch two layout by `BottomNavigationBar`

Every time switching the bar, it loads `initState()` and lost all variables in `_BodyLayoutState()`

So, I wonder,

1.Keeping the contents(`List<Article> articles = [];`) in `State` is not good?? I should keep contents in upper class like `_MyHomePageState`?

2.Is there any way to keep contents in `State` and not dispose when switching ???

These are source code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new MyHomePage(),
        "/browser": (_) => new Text("not use"),
      }
    );
  }
}
class Article{
  String title;
  String url;
  Article();
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title; 
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _myLayouts = [];
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myLayouts = [
      new BodyLayout("latest", key: Key('1')),
      new BodyLayout("pop",key: Key('2')),
    ];
  }
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    print("itemTapped :" +index.toString());
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index; 
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      //  title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _myLayouts[_currentIndex],

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('latest'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('pop'),
        ),
      ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}


class BodyLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mode;
  BodyLayout(this.mode, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyLayoutState createState() => _BodyLayoutState();
}
class _BodyLayoutState extends State<BodyLayout>{
  List<Article> articles = [];
  bool loading = true;
  bool firstLoaded = false;
  int page = 1;
  @override 
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    print ("init:" + widget.mode);
    if (firstLoaded == false){
      print("I don't want to load twice");
      _callApi();
    }
  }

  void _callApi() {
    var a = Article();
    a.title = widget.mode;
    a.url = widget.mode;
    articles.add(a);
    firstLoaded == true;
    setState((){
      loading = false;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(loading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: articles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(articles[index].title),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) to display your BodyLayout's.
Just change

```
body: _myLayouts[_currentIndex],
```

to

```
body: IndexedStack(children: _myLayouts, index: _currentIndex,),
```

Comment: Thank you it doesn't dispose the layout each times. so it is great solution for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Provider package to store that information https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.